# Enable Media Volume Slider in Android application

Tags: android

Some Android programs trigger the "media volume" slider when the hardware volume up/down buttons are pressed. My application seems to set the ringer volume when the hardware buttons are pressed.

How would I enable the media volume slider?

I would hate for users to have to go into their settings to change the media volume when they use my application.

Comment: Be sure to test the behaviour of the buttons during playback and while not playing sounds. During playback the media control should be the default for the buttons. But christophers method will enable the users to change the volume at every time the activity is active.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just call [`Activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29) in your Activity's `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
private AudioManager audio;
```

Inside onCreate:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Override onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```